# Building apache beam sdk harness for portable runner - name problem

Tags: python, gradle, build, apache-beam

Trying to build the SDK harness for the portable runner.  Following the instructions found: 
 https://beam.apache.org/documentation/runners/flink/

The SDK harness fails when building with an error, the code run is:

`./gradlew :sdks:python:container:docker`

The error
Execution failed for task ':sdks:python:container:docker'.

> name is a required docker configuration item.

This occurs on both Debian and Ubuntu across a couple recent versions of each.

Comment: dev@beam.apache.org might be the better place for this question.

Answer (score 1):

This changed recently, you need to specify the python version:

```
./gradlew :sdks:python:container:py2:docker
```

Other currently valid options include:

```
:sdks:python:container:py35:docker
:sdks:python:container:py36:docker
:sdks:python:container:py37:docker
```